# From the minibuffer, how can I get the file pointed to in dired?

Tags: dired, minibuffer

I'd like to write elisp function with the following functionality:

1. It can be invoked from the minibuffer, and it will then relate to the latest selected window buffer.
2. If the selected buffer is in dired-mode, it should insert the file pointed to by dired
3. Otherwise insert the buffer name of the file

This is what I have got so far:

```lisp
;; Doesn't work as intended when in minibuffer invoked from dired mode!
(defun get-nondir-filename-from-dired-or-buffer ()
  "Returns either the filename of the buffer or the file pointed to in a dired buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((winbuf (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window))))
  (insert
   (shell-quote-argument
    (file-name-nondirectory
     (if (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode winbuf)
             'dired-mode)
         (dired-get-filename)  ;; <- How can I get filename from dired?
       (buffer-file-name winbuf)))))))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

Found it! I needed to do `(save-window-excursion (switch-to-buffer ...)` before invoking `(dired-get-filename)`. Here is the final solution:

```lisp
(defun get-nondir-filename-from-dired-or-buffer ()
  "Returns either the filename of the buffer or the file pointed to in a dired buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((winbuf (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window))))
  (insert
   (shell-quote-argument
    (file-name-nondirectory
     (if (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode winbuf)
             'dired-mode)
         (save-window-excursion
           (switch-to-buffer winbuf)
           (dired-get-filename))  
       (buffer-file-name winbuf)))))))
```

For reference, here is a cleaner version, where I have extracted the function to get the buffer or dired filename to a function:

```lisp
(defun get-referenced-filename ()
  "Get the filename of the buffer or the file pointed to by dired"
  (let* ((winbuf (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window))))
    (if (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode winbuf)
            'dired-mode)
        (save-window-excursion
          (switch-to-buffer winbuf)
          (dired-get-filename))
      (buffer-file-name winbuf))))

(defun name-of-the-file ()
  "Gets the shell quoted name of the file the current buffer points to"
  (interactive)
  (insert (shell-quote-argument (get-referenced-filename))))

(defun name-nondirectory-of-the-file ()
  "Gets the shell quoted non-directory name of the file the current buffer points to"
  (interactive)
  (insert (shell-quote-argument (file-name-nondirectory (get-referenced-filename)))))
```